# ImageView returning as null in android

Tags: android, android-asynctask, imageview, switch-statement

So the issue is I have a set of data inside a listview that outputs onto a page. I would like to be able to change an image based on what rating is retrieved. But for some reason when I try to set the ImageView as a variable and find the ID it returns as null. Is there any way I can retrieve this any other way?

```
if (jo.getString("RatingValue").contains("-1")) {
                        listPlaces.add(jo.getString("BusinessName") + "\n" + jo.getString("AddressLine1") + "\n"
                                + jo.getString("AddressLine2") + "\n" + jo.getString("AddressLine3") + "\n"
                                + jo.getString("PostCode") + "\nRating: EXEMPT\nDated: "
                                + jo.getString("RatingDate") + "\n");
                    } else {
                        if (jo.getString("RatingValue").contains("0")) {
                            changeImg(0);
                            System.out.println("Result 0");
                        } else if (jo.getString("RatingValue").contains("1")) {
                            changeImg(1);
                            System.out.println("Result 1");
                        } else if (jo.getString("RatingValue").contains("2")) {
                            changeImg(2);
                            System.out.println("Result 2");
                        } else if (jo.getString("RatingValue").contains("3")) {
                            changeImg(3);
                            System.out.println("Result 3");
                        } else if (jo.getString("RatingValue").contains("4")) {
                            changeImg(4);
                            System.out.println("Result 4");
                        } else if (jo.getString("RatingValue").contains("5")) {
                            changeImg(5);
                            System.out.println("Result 5");
                        }
```

this is the if statements and then here is my method to change the image

```
 private void changeImg(int img) {

    final ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.icon);

            System.out.println(imageView + "outside");
            switch (img) {
                case 0:
                    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.rating0);
                case 1:
                    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.rating1);
                case 2:
                    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.rating2);
                case 3:
                    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.rating3);
                case 4:
                    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.rating4);
                case 5:
                    System.out.println(imageView + "inside");
                    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.rating5);

            }
}
```

without the imageView statements it works but without changing the image.

Also I will add that the method is called inside an AysncTask class

Thanks in advance.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal">
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/rating0"/>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/data"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Remove the final modifier in front of the ImageView.

Comment: I have removed the Final declaration and it still is returning as null

Comment: Are you sure that the resource ids are valid?

Comment: The ids are correct but I'm using a listView that contains the text and an image, I will update my post with the XML files showing the "icon" variable.

Answer (score 0):

All UI related stuff must be done at UI/Main thread, so if you want to change image of an `ImageView` at another thread (for example, `AsyncTask`). You should use

```
MyActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run(){
        // change ui here
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks for the reply but I still am getting this nullPointerException error and I surrounded my code with your runOnUiThread idea.

Comment: @ChrisHoward Which line does throw that exception?

Comment: `case 5:
                    System.out.println(imageView + "inside");
                    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.rating5); //error line`

Comment: There is also an image saved inside the correct folder, and the system.out.println returns as "nulloutside"

Comment: Did you check this `imageView` is not `null`?

Comment: yeah, `imageView` always returns as null whenever I `system.out.println(imageView)`

Comment: but that's basically what I want to find out is how can I get it so `imageView` doesn't return as null

Comment: @ChrisHoward Make sure that id you've passed to `findViewById` is exactly what points to your desired `ImageView`.

Comment: yeah the ID for Icon is correct, but for some reason it does not retrieve the information, there is the original XML for the activity and I also have an extra XML file for the List which is shown above but I'm unsure as to why this is returning as null if I have used the correct variable names.